# Delphi: shellexecute and sw_hide

Tags: delphi, shellexecute

I'm trying to run the application is hidden, but the application form is still visible.

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'app.exe', nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
```

How to run a hidden application in Delphi?

Comment: the SW_HIDE on ShellExecute has little power. It is only a suggestion, not a demand. Whether it is hidden or not depends on the application. Something like @Pateman's solution where you get a handle to the process and hide it after it's started will work more reliably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using `CreateProcess` instead, because it returns the process ID of the newly launched application and you can use it to get the window's handle. Here's a function I have been using, maybe you can take away unnecessary fragments and adapt it to your needs?

```pascal
// record to store window information
TWndInfo = record
  pid: DWord;
  WndHandle: HWND;
  width, height: Integer;
end;
PWndInfo = ^TWndInfo;
```

```
{$HINTS OFF}
{ .: ExecNewProcess :. }
function ExecNewProcess(const ProgramName: String;
  const StartHidden, WaitForInput: Boolean; out WndInfo: TWndInfo): Boolean;
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  R: TRect;
  SL: TStringList;

  {$REGION 'EnumProcess'}
  function EnumProcess(hHwnd: HWND; lParam: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
  var
    WndInfo: PWndInfo;
    pid: DWORD;
  begin
    Result := True;

    WndInfo := PWndInfo(lParam);
    if (WndInfo = nil) or (hHwnd = 0) then
      exit;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hHwnd, pid);
    if (pid = WndInfo.PID) then
    begin
      if (WndInfo.WndHandle = 0) and (IsWindowVisible(hHwnd)) then
        WndInfo.WndHandle := hHwnd;
      //Result := False;
    end;
  end;
  {$ENDREGION}

begin
  Result := False;

  ZeroMemory(@StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo));
  ZeroMemory(@ProcInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation));

  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  if StartHidden then
  begin
    StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or StartInfo.dwFlags;
    StartInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE;
  end;

  Result := CreateProcess(PChar(ProgramName), nil, nil, nil, False, 0, nil,
    nil, StartInfo, ProcInfo);
  try
    if Result then
    begin
      WndInfo.WndHandle := 0;
      WndInfo.PID := ProcInfo.dwProcessId;

      if WaitForInput then
        WaitForInputIdle(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

      EnumWindows(@EnumProcess, Integer(@WndInfo));
      if (WndInfo.WndHandle <> 0) then
      begin
        if (StartHidden) then
          ShowWindow(WndInfo.WndHandle, SW_HIDE);
        Windows.GetWindowRect(WndInfo.WndHandle, R);

        WndInfo.Width := R.Right - R.Left;
        WndInfo.Height := R.Bottom - R.Top;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
  end;
end;
{$HINTS ON}
```

Comment: [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(28): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TWndInfo'

Comment: It's just a record which I am using to return some information for later use. You don't really need it. Basically strip out the essential parts from the snippet I posted.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

it is up to the application to decide how to handle the SW_HIDE. Thus the application has to fetch the message and hide itself, as far as i see...

Comment: In **some** cases, if the other application will allow, you can use the process id of the new process and tell Windows to hide it (as posted by Pateman above). But, yes, if the destination app isn't yours (don't have source), and the destination app likes to forcefully show its self, then no you cannot hide it from another app. But it could be as simple as right after launching it, tell windows to hide it.